# Why TCP/IP monitor doesn't catch soap messages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am novice in soap and jax-ws.

After  reading many information I knew that eclipse can catch soap messages, But I have problem with it.

my publisher

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/WS/Greeting",
                new GreetingImpl());
    }
```

my cient

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        GreetingImplService service = new GreetingImplService();
        Greeting greeting = service.getGreetingImplPort();
        System.out.println("------->>  Call Started");
        System.out.println(greeting.sayHello("friend !!!"));
        System.out.println("------->>  Call Ended");
    }
```

When I invoke client in Console I see

```
------->>  Call Started
Hello, Welcom to jax-ws friend !!!
------->>  Call Ended
```

Therefore it is working service.

But in TCP|IP monitor I see empty list.

my configuration of TCP|IP monitor
[image]

What Do I make wrong?

please, help)

Answer (score 5):

I think that the probelm is that your client is pointing directly to port 8081 (the port of the ws) so the tcp/ip monitor does not come into play. Since the monitor is listening on port 8080, your client should use this endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting
```

The TCP/IP monitor will receive the http request and then it will forward the message to

```
http://localhost:8081/WS/Greeting
```

To alter the endpoint used by the client you have 2 possibilities:

- If the client uses a local wsdl document (for example you have saved a copy of the wsdl on your file system and used it to call wsimport), you can modify the endpoint in it (look at the element service at the end of the wsdl). The stub returned by service.getGreetingImplPort() reads the endpoint from the wsdl.
- You can use this instruction in the main method of the client

  ```
    ((BindingProvider) greeting).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting");
  ```